# binding radio button value to the controller (using angularjs 1.5)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a problem sending a radio button value to my controller here is my html :

```
<input class="i-radio" name="_rate"  ng-model="rate"  ng-value="'-100'" type="radio" />-5 star (-100)</label>

<button class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-4" type="submit" ng-click="evaluation(rate)">Evaluez</button>
```

my controller :

```
 $scope.evaluation = function(rate){
    console.log(rate);
}
```

my problem is the rate.value is always undefined

Comment: What is the error ? Also you should try to provide a fiddle demonstrating the issue if possible.

Comment: my problem is when ever i click on my submit button the rate value is always undefined

Comment: do check it  then submit?

Comment: ofc i checked it and then submited

Comment: try making a demo of your problem code in jsfiddle, that will help to better understand where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

i figure it out my mistake was in my html the class i-radio was somehow blocking the check of the radio button

Answer (score 0):

It's all alright, just you didn't specified any controller I think, try this code that I write for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<script>
var app = angular.module("angApp", []);
app.controller("angCtrl", function($scope) {
 $scope.evaluation = function(rate){
    console.log(rate);
}
});

</script>
<div ng-app="angApp" ng-controller="angCtrl">

<input class="i-radio" name="_rate"  ng-model="rate"  ng-value="'-100'" type="radio" />-5 star (-100)</label>

<button class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-4" type="submit" ng-click="evaluation(rate)">Evaluez</button>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope helped you ---

Comment: thank you #Alireza but the problem was in my html i was using the iCheck plugin and it was not working with my angular directive now evrything works fine :)